# UIFont: How to change all fonts in any view in app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uifont

Our app as many others concist of MANY different components such as UIButton, UITextField, UILabel, etc (not UISearchBar) for displaying and editing text. Most components are setup in Interface Builder. What is the most efficient way of replacing all system fonts with a custom font?

Should I categorize UIFont to always return our custom font?
Or should I iterate over all the xib-files xml and replace the font from there?
Recomendations and other options is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 5 brings new API for customizing the standard UI that should make changing the fonts dead-easy. Depends on your OS version requirements.

Comment: Great! Required OS for this app is iOS 5. :)

Comment: Where can I find more info about this API?

Comment: It’s still under NDA, so I can’t give you any public pointers. I suppose you do have a developer account and therefore also access to [WWDC 2011 videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/). There’s a whole talk dedicated to UI customization. It’s boring, but will give you precisely the information you need.

Comment: That's just sooo great! I finally understand how it works! This is AWESOME! I was able to change all fonts in any component by altering the default font of UILabel!

Comment: only sad thing about UIAppearance is that UIFont is tightly coupled with fontsize. sad...